# Alljoyn Message TimeStamp in Android

Tags: android, alljoyn

In the course of working on an Alljoyn application for Android and iOS and investigating the Unity bindings, I noticed that both the iOS and Unity bindings have "message" object passed as a parameter to the method handlers that includes a timestamp from the bus.  Is there anything like that for Android?

Comment: nopes thats not the case with android, there seems to be no timestamp sent across in the bushandler.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I never found this property for Android.  I was trying to use it to synchronize time between the host and clients.  I ended up just adding a simple bus object method to return the current host time, which I periodically update and store on the clients.  For most updates the round trip latency was a couple milliseconds, which was perfectly acceptable for my application.